# Connecting to DB via Quarkus

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, quarkus

I have recently started a new Java application and I am trying to use the Quarkus framework. I have a DB (MySQL) running on a docker container that has exposed the port 3306, I confirmed I can access this through MySQL Workbench.

Reading [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource) doc online, I followed the steps to setup a JDBC connection. I added the `agroal` and `jdbc-mysql` extensions to Quarkus and have the following in my `application.properties`

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=mysql
quarkus.datasource.username=<username>
quarkus.datasource.password=<password>
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/messanger?useSSL=false&autoreconnect=true
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.acquisition-timeout=PT1M
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.min-size=1
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-size=16
```

I then created a class to manage and setup the DB at the start when the application first runs;

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class DatabaseManager {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DatabaseManager.class);

    private final Jdbi jdbi;
    private final DataSource dataSource;
    private boolean initialized;

    @Inject
    public DatabaseManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        jdbi = Jdbi.create(dataSource);
        jdbi.installPlugin(new SqlObjectPlugin());
    }

    /**
     * Lazy initialization of SoR DB.
     */
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        LOGGER.info("Lazy init of {}", getClass().getSimpleName());

        jdbi.getConfig(SqlStatements.class).setQueryTimeout(30);

        Flyway flyway = Flyway.configure()
                .locations("classpath:sql")
                .baselineOnMigrate(true)
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .load();
        flyway.migrate();

        if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
            setSqlLogging();
        }

        setInitialized(true);
        LOGGER.info("Initialization complete");
    }

}
```

I have only included upto the `PostConstruct` as that's the most important parts. But when I have the application running, I attach a debugger and put a breakpoint in the `PostConstruct` method, it never gets hit!!! I don't understand this as but then I tried looking at the console output of Quarkus as it's starting up and all it shows is;

```
2020-07-31 07:34:37,932 WARN  [io.qua.dep.QuarkusAugmentor] (main) Using Java versions older than 11 to build Quarkus applications is deprecated and will be disallowed in a future release!
2020-07-31 07:34:40,247 INFO  [io.agr.pool] (Quarkus Main Thread) Datasource '<default>': Initial size smaller than min. Connections will be created when necessary
2020-07-31 07:34:40,495 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) platform 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT on JVM (powered by Quarkus 1.6.1.Final) started in 2.616s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8082
2020-07-31 07:34:40,497 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Profile dev activated. Live Coding activated.
2020-07-31 07:34:40,497 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) Installed features: [agroal, cache, cdi, flyway, jdbc-mysql, mutiny, narayana-jta, resteasy, smallrye-context-propagation, smallrye-fault-tolerance, smallrye-health]
```

The Datasource is set to `default` even though I followed the config doc (link above) and was expecting the datasource to be `mysql`.

Is there something obvious I am missing here?

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Did you try to get jdbi working in native mode?

Comment: use **AgroalDataSource** instead of **DataSource**.

Answer (score 1):

Beans are lazilly created, and your `@PostConstruct` methods will be called at bean instanciation time.

This means that your `@PostConstruct` methods will be called the first time you use your `DatabaseManager` bean, not at application start time.

If you want a method to run when the application sart, you need to use our lyfecycle events: https://quarkus.io/guides/lifecycle#listening-for-startup-and-shutdown-events

Be aware also that unused beans are remove by Arc (the CDI implementation of Quarkus) this can also be the cause of an initialization method not being called, more informations here: https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-reference#remove_unused_beans